# graphql filtering unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm learning Ruby on Rails with GraphQL and following this tutorial: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/7-filtering/
I'm at the last part about writing a unit test and I ran into an error while running `bundle exec rails test`. Here are my files, they're almost identical to the tutorial:

`app > graphql > resolvers > links_search.rb`

```
require 'search_object'
require 'search_object/plugin/graphql'

class Resolvers::LinksSearch < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver 
    include SearchObject.module(:graphql)

    scope { Link.all }

    type types[Types::LinkType], null: false

    class LinkFilter < ::Types::BaseInputObject
        argument :OR, [self], required: false
        argument :description_contains, String, required: false
        argument :url_contains, String, required: false
    end

    option :filter, type: LinkFilter, with: :apply_filter

    def apply_filter(scope, value)
        branches = normalize_filters(value).reduce { |a, b| a.or(b) }
        scope.merge branches
    end

    def normalize_filters(value, branches = [])
        scope = Link.all
        scope = scope.where('description LIKE ?', "%#{value[:description_contains]}%") if value[:description_contains]
        scope = scope.where('url LIKE ?', "%#{value[:url_contains]}%") if value[:url_contains]

        branches << scope

        value[:OR].reduce(branches) { |s, v| normalize_filters(v, s) } if value[:OR].present?

        branches
    end
end
```

`app > graphql > types > query_type.rb`

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    # Add `node(id: ID!) and `nodes(ids: [ID!]!)`
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodeField
    include GraphQL::Types::Relay::HasNodesField

    # Add root-level fields here.
    # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.
    field :all_links, resolver: Resolvers::LinksSearch
  end
end
```

`test > graphql > mutations > resolvers > links_search_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

module Resolvers
    class LinksSearchTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
        def find(args)
            Resolvers::LinksSearch.call(nil, args, nil)
        end

        def create_user
            User.create name: 'example', email: 'example', password: 'example'
        end

        def create_link(**attributes)
            Link.create! attributes.merge(user: create_user)
        end

        test 'filter option' do
            link1 = create_link description: 'test1', url: 'test1.com'
            link1 = create_link description: 'test2', url: 'test2.com'
            link1 = create_link description: 'test3', url: 'test3.com'
            link1 = create_link description: 'test4', url: 'test4.com'

            result = find(
                filter: {
                    description_contains: 'test1',
                    OR: [{
                        url_contains: 'test2',
                        OR: [{
                            url_contains: 'test3'
                        }]
                    }, {
                        description_contains: 'test2'
                    }]
                }
            )

            assert_equal result.map(&:description).sort, [link1, link2, link3].map(&:description).sort
        end
    end
end
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Resolvers::LinksSearchTest#test_filter_option:
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for Resolvers::LinksSearch:Class
    test/graphql/mutations/resolvers/links_search_test.rb:6:in `find'
    test/graphql/mutations/resolvers/links_search_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:LinksSearchTest>'
```

There seems to be no method `call` in `LinksSearch`, not even in the repository of the tutorial I checked on GitHub. I'm not exactly sure what to do here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you found any solution ?